# How to run google tests completely isolated from each other?

Tags: c++, googletest, address-sanitizer

I want to use Address Sanitizer to detect runtime errors while unit tests are running. However, Address Sanitizer terminates the app when it finds the first error so I can't see an information of all found runtime errors in one report. It would be possible if I could run google tests isolated from each other, and termination of one test woudn't influence other ones.

Comment: assuming you're talking about clang address sanitizer, here's a quote from the official FAQ: "Can AddressSanitizer continue running after reporting first error?A: Yes it can[...]This is somewhat experimental[...]To enable continue-after-error, compile with **-fsanitize-recover=address** and then run your code with **ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0**."

Comment: of course, the more errors there are, the higher the chance of spurious errors is ...

Comment: Okay, AddressSanitizer can continue running after reporting first error but actually I need a bit different behavior. If there is an error in a test method, I want AddressSanitizer report this error, break execution of this test method and run the next one.

Comment: generally speaking, I don't think it would be a wise thing to do. ASAN warns you that memory corruption occurred (hence your code has undefined behaviour); as a result, successive tests may turn out false negatives/positives anyway ...

Answer (score 2):

You can run specific test cases in Google Test, one by one.

From: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests

> By default, a Google Test program runs all tests the user has defined.
>   Sometimes, you want to run only a subset of the tests (e.g. for
>   debugging or quickly verifying a change). If you set the GTEST_FILTER
>   environment variable or the --gtest_filter flag to a filter string,
>   Google Test will only run the tests whose full names (in the form of
>   TestCaseName.TestName) match the filter.
>
> The format of a filter is a ':'-separated list of wildcard patterns
>   (called the positive patterns) optionally followed by a '-' and
>   another ':'-separated pattern list (called the negative patterns). A
>   test matches the filter if and only if it matches any of the positive
>   patterns but does not match any of the negative patterns.
>
> A pattern may contain '*' (matches any string) or '?' (matches any
>   single character). For convenience, the filter '*-NegativePatterns'
>   can be also written as '-NegativePatterns'.
>
> For example:
>
> ./foo_test Has no flag, and thus runs all its tests.
>
> ./foo_test --gtest_filter=* Also runs everything, due to the single
>   match-everything * value.
>
> ./foo_test --gtest_filter=FooTest.* Runs everything in test case
>   FooTest.
>
> ./foo_test --gtest_filter=*Null*:*Constructor* Runs any test whose
>   full name contains either "Null" or "Constructor".
>
> ./foo_test --gtest_filter=-*DeathTest.* Runs all non-death tests.
>
> ./foo_test --gtest_filter=FooTest.*-FooTest.Bar Runs everything in
>   test case FooTest except FooTest.Bar.

Comment: However, any error happened in one test from a set will terminate execution of all other tests from the set.

Comment: If you have `n` tests in your test file, then you run your test `n` times each with a different value of `--gtest_filter` that picks a different test. It's not automated, though.